# Compare columns in two indentical tables with respect to primary key and return mismatch rows in MySQL

Tags: mysql

```
Table1
id | Ans1| Ans2
 1 |yes | no
 2 | no| yes
 3 | no| no

Table2
id | Ans1| Ans2
 1 |yes | no
 2 | yes| no
 3 | no| yes
```

Is there a way that i can return only the rows that are mismatch. here in this example i want the last two rows to be returned except the 1st row.

Comment: I tried SELECT * FROM `table2` minus select * from table1 but it returns all rows from table2

Comment: Minus - that's oracle, are you using oracle or mysql?

Comment: MySQL - I'm very new to this field and I'm trying to experiment and learn from stack

Comment: Fair enough but beware that sql dialects are manufacturer specific in certain areas and you may have to google for mysql equivalent of some process you come across from another dialect.

Comment: Hi. Please read [ask] and hits googling 'meta.stackexchange homework'. Also [mcve]. And clearly exactly explain "mismatch"--what and what do not agree on what? Also edit clarifications into your post, not into comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with a JOIN of the tables. Your query may look like this (and there are other types of join you can use to achieve this results

```
select t1.*, t2.*
from Table1 t1
inner join Table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id and (t1.Ans1 <> t2.Ans1 OR t1.Ans2 <> t2.Ans2)
```

Hopes this helps

Comment: Worked like charm, Thank you so much!